# How to stay at the current width/height after jQuery click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on the following code, the page moves up at the top. How can I keep the current width/ height and not move the user at the beginning of the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#click").click(function() {
    //some things in here
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigating to the top is the default behaviour of such a link, and can be prevented by calling `e.preventDefault()`, where `e` is the jQuery event argument:

```
$("#click").click(function(e) { // <-- `e` is passed to the function
    e.preventDefault();

    //some things in here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `#click` is an anchor element, `<a id="click" href=""></a>`, then you get that top-of-page behavior. So either do what [@pimvdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508813/1165832) advised or use a different element (like a `span` or `div`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the e.preventDefault() or just return false, return false contains preventDefault() and also prevents event bubbling.

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    // something here
    return false
});
```